# Symbols in Linux due to Version Change

Tags: linux, php

We have linked PHP Code with C++ code using PHP Extension code (written in C++ only)... which all were working fine in 32bit OS.

Now we changed the version of many s/w as the OS version is changed to 64bit. We Compiled the C++ code which was previously running fine using 64bit gcc to 32bit ".so" file it shown many errors and we cleared all those and finally compiled successfully. But during linking with PHP it's showing:

```
undefined symbol: _ZTV5Temps" error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `c++filt` to demangle the name:

```
$ c++filt -n _ZTV5Temps
vtable for Temps
```

My guess (given the lack of context) is you have a reference to `Temps` (class) in a module that has not been recompiled/relinked.

Comment: Hi, thanks.. your answer helped me to solve that error but now am getting one more error as below:  "undefined symbol: _ZTIN3ocl11CRExceptionE " i tried using the same command o/p as below:
"# c++filt -n _ZTIN3ocl11CRExceptionE
typeinfo for ocl::CRException "  but am not clear with this pls, help me

Comment: OCL is an Oracle C++ class library, you'll need to rebuild that if you are using libraries compiled in the old setup (even if it was still 32-bit, C++ binaries and libraries should use the same compiler to avoid ABI headaches).

Comment: @ mr.spuratic Please be specific on which libraries has to be recompiled ??? I checked into the OCL libraries there are only .h files are there and there is a class "CRException" these path i have included for compiling my code in Makfile.. Now am bit confused to approach this issue pls, help me.

Comment: OCL isn't something I'm familiar with, I just searched for the function name [to find it](http://www.devart.com/ocl/download.html). If I had to guess I'd say it's `libocl.so` and/or `libocl.x.y.so`. I was going to suggest you try a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640215/typeinfo-for-oclcrexception)...