# Typeinfo for ocl::CRException

Tags: c++, linux, g++, exception-specification

I tried to run my C++ program using g++ but am getting following exception: 
**"typeinfo for ocl::CRException"** am using ocl namespace containing CRException class..  Please, help me on this.

Here is the code where am including OCL classes :

```
#ifndef VOIDSOFT_ADA2_LIND_HH

#define VOIDSOFT_ADA2_LIND_HH
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <queue>
#include <map>
#include <ocl.h>
#include "threaded.hh"

using namespace std;
using namespace ocl;

class circuit;

class Lind: public Threaded 
{
public:
    typedef int lookup_t;

private:
    OraConnection connection;
    pthread_mutex_t *done_m;
    queue<pthread_t> *q;
    lookup_t type;

public:
    circuit *c;
    Lind();
    ~Lind();

    void *run();    

    map<string, pair<string, string> > *getnodes(string);

    bool connect();
    void disconnect();

private:
    circuit *getcircuitinfo(string, circuit *c = 0);               
    void bindInStr(OraQuery &q, string arg, string bindvar, map<string, string> *properties);

    map<string, pair<string, string> > *node2name(string);
};

/* Lookup types */
namespace LindLookupTypes {
    /* Get overlying */
    const int OL = 0x001;
    /* Get underlying */
    const int UL = 0x002;
}
#endif /* VOIDSOFT_ADA2_LIND_HH */
```

Answer (score 0):

It usually means you forgot to define (implement) a virtual method somewhere. Check that all virtual methods of `ocl::CRException` are defined and that the object file where they are defined is actually linked to your code.

If it doesn't help, edit the answer and show us the code for `CRException`.

Comment: Is this can be because of Version problem? I wrote the code in GCC 2.3 and compiled the same in GCC 3.4.. I cleared many errors. now the program is compiling properly but getting `ocl::CRException` .. do i need to change any thing because of version change??

Comment: @viswa: It's hard to guess but it is certainly possible. If you could post some code, preferably a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), we might be able to help you. Just edit the answer and *afterwards*, reply to this comment so I am notified that there is some code to look at.

Comment: I added the code where am including ocl namespace.This code was first compiled in gcc 2.x and now am compiling the same in 4.6. It shown many compile time error i fixed all those by small changes and now its showing "undefined symbol : _ZTIN3ocl11CRExceptionE " which was ocl::CRExpection

Comment: @viswa: The code you showed is almost certainly not the problem. Since you made a big jump wrt GCC versions, make sure you recompiled/reinstalled OCL and try if the problem persists.

Comment: I reinstalled ocl previously but still i was getting the same error. I checked even my makefile for lib directory and its same as the directory where i installed

Comment: @viswa: I'm out of ideas, it seems to be too specific. Maybe ask on some OCL mailing list, given that there is one? Good luck!